# Sql Query! Can someone explain this?

Tags: sql

[image]

Q1 : List employees who have the biggest salary in their departments

Q2 : List employees that don't have a boss in the same department

Q1 Answer)

```
Select e.name, Max_Sal.Sal 
From Employees e 
  JOIN (Select d.DepartmentID,max(e.Salary) As Sal 
        From Employees e 
          JOIN Departments d ON e.DepartmentId=d.DepartmentId 
        Group by d.departmentID
  ) As Max_Sal 
    ON e.DepartmentId=Max_Sal.DepartmentID 
    and e.Salary=Max_Sal.Sal;
```

In Q2, I don't understand the question, [don't have a boss in the same department]. How to know boss is in which department?

Comment: Hint: Self join!

Comment: Thanks you for your help. You means that
Select e.Name,e.DepartmentID From Employees e JOIN Departments d ON e.DepartmentId=d.DepartmentId JOIN Employees m ON m.EmployeeID=e.BossID and e.DepartmentId<>m.DepartmentId

is the right query???

Comment: Please google 'stackexchange homework' & [ask]. Show what parts you've tried. Read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy: While the rules you list are indeed SO's rules, keep in mind that OP's problem is that **he doesn't understand the question**, which logically means that he's unable to provide an MCVE since he doesn't know what is being requested.

Comment: @Flater That doesn't stop them from giving DDL & example input and saying whatever sense they can make of part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Q2 : List employees that don't have a boss in the same department

There is a slight trick to this question.

---

**1 - Join**

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees b on e.BossId = b.EmployeeId
```

Notice the following:

- We've used the `Employees` table twice, but I've given them separate names. `e` is every employee; and `b` is that employee's boss.
- We use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to account for the possibility that an employee does not have a boss (`b` will be `NULL`) If we had used an `INNER JOIN`, the employees with no boss would have been omitted from the result.

Now, we have a table of every employee, connected to their boss. But we still need to filter the list as requested.

---

**2 - Filter**

There are three possible states that an employee can be in:

1. They have no boss.
2. They have a boss, who works in the same department.
3. They have a boss, who works in a different department.

It's important to realize that the requested output needs to contain both the employees in situation 3 and the employees in situation 1. We should only omit the employees in situation 2.

Using pseudo-SQL, this means your query should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_data
WHERE
    situation_1_applies
  OR
    situation_3_applies
```

The individual filters are not that hard to write:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees b on e.BossId = b.EmployeeId
WHERE
    -- situation_1_applies
    -- When b is NULL, all of b's columns are NULL
    b.DepartmentId is NULL
  OR
    -- situation_3_applies
    b.DepartmentId <> e.DepartmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a boss in the same department, so you can think bossID in Employees table is null. So you can write an SQL query for a group all of the people have the same department who have the bossID is null :), So it not real because employees have to have a boss (not null), If you show me full field of table, maybe I will show you exactly my answer.

In the other hand, you can think, They have the same bossID, so your mission will write an SQL query for a group all of the people have the same bossID but they have a different department.

I have an example MySQL query (for same bossID but different department):

```
    SELECT * FROM Employees as e
    INNER JOIN department d ON d.departmentId = e.deparmentId
    WHERE e.DepartmentID in (
        SELECT DepartmentID
            FROM Employees
            GROUP BY DepartmentID
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 /* it's fixed */
    ) AND e.BossID = 2 /* any value of bossID you want, you can join it with Boss table */
```

===== Update my answer =====

I have an idea for the question.

Anyone must have a boss, and boss also is an employee in table SQL.

```
    '    employeeName   '    department name '   boss name
    --------------------------------------------------------
    '    King           '    Director        '               
    '    Victor         '    Marketing       '   King
    '    Angela         '    Product         '   King
    '    Ken            '    Marketing       '   Victor
    '    LaLa           '    Marketing       '   Victor
    '    Jery           '    Business        '   Ken
```

And because don't have a boss in the same department -> their department can't have their boss. => the result as the following table:

```
    '    employeeName   '    department name '   boss name
    --------------------------------------------------------
    '    King           '    Director        '               
    '    Victor         '    Marketing       '   King
    '    Angela         '    Product         '   King
    '    Jery           '    Business        '   Ken
```

If you have a right way to understand this question, you can post here for everyone can understand. Thanks

Comment: Thanks you for you help. I showed all the field and all the table. For more, please visit https://www.jitbit.com/news/181-jitbits-sql-interview-questions/

Comment: Okay, I just see your comment, I will check it

Comment: I edited my answer to your question. I just show my idea, I don't have code SQL for this, You can consider it :))

Comment: Subqueries like these are a bad idea in general. They work, but they have incredibly low performance (you essentially have to run a copy of that subquery for **every** individual employee). While you may not notice an issue for a small demo database, the problem exponentially explodes in a real life enterprise database. Given the structure of the tables, joining them is a much better approach here.